# How to translate "series" (computers)?

Tags: informatique, noms

I wonder about the right French word to use to translate "series" (Computer context).

For instance, the

> IBM 700/7000 series

[Wikipedia (fr)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_IBM_700/7000) uses "série" in this case, but that doesn't sound right to me.

> Série IBM 700/7000

Could be wrong, but wouldn't "gamme" sound better?

> IBM gamme 700/7000

What do you think?

Comment: _Gamme_ est bien aussi, mais l'ordre des mots est le même que pour _Série_: _Gamme IBM 700/7000_.

Comment: Can you explain why it doesn't sound right to you? I mean, in english the **xxx _series_** indicates the **series numbered xxx**. In french the **_série_ xxx** indicates the **_série_ numérotée xxx**. What is wrong in it according to you?

Comment: @Aweuzegaga Maybe because my French sucks?

Comment: I am not asking or commenting your level in french... My question is, can you elaborate on why it doesn't sound right to you? Is it just a feeling? Do you think _série_ is a bad equivalent for _serie_ in this context and if yes why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, a ***gamme*** is a range of products while a ***série*** is a sequence of products.

They might be interchangeable like in your example but beware that it is not always the case.

A *gamme* often encompass the whole range of the products a manufacturer is building while a serie is a subset of it.

For example, the *gamme* of cars sold by BMW is a suite of *séries*: *Série 1*, *Série 2*, *Série 3* and so on.

There are also some idioms like:

- ***Fin de série***: The last models of a kind being produced.
- ***Série limitée***: A short number of models produced with specific features (either optional ones included for the same price, or unique features or quality). Compare to ***Gamme limitée*** that means a narrow range of products.

There is also ***de série*** that means either being included in the standard model (opposed to ***en option***), or being available as a standard model (opposed to ***prototype*** or ***sur mesure***).

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with both, but as @mouviciel noted the order of the words would be different.
In fact I would go for :

> La gamme 700/7000 d'IBM